# "Bad file descriptor" when reading from FD 3 pointing to a temp file

Tags: bash

My question is inspired by [this SO answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181938).

Consider the script:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
exec 3>"$tmpfile"
rm "$tmpfile"

>&3 cat <<EOS
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS

cat <&3
```

You can [play with it online here](https://tio.run/##TYqxCsIwFAD39xWPthRdGmKWWmo3Z4d@QQxPE9rEYJ6Qv49oHZyO4@6qky2lxploQMsc0yDEK7jcJdZmoWysDnfqzMMLLWQvj6qHGtjHm1vp1Oz8wuTjHiiTQTVVzS9V8PT4ZzC1Co1mHMfzZYbVBUK54bBBwSfA92lVKW8).

I expect it print out the 3 lines, but in fact I get a "Bad file descriptor" error.

Why does the above not work?  How can it be altered so that it does?

Note: The error persists even if you delete the 3rd line: `rm "$tmpfile"`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You only opened file descriptor 3 for writing, not reading. Change that line to

```
exec 3<>"$tmpfile"
```

and the bad file descriptor error will go away.

However, `cat <&3` still won't produce any output, because the file pointer is still at the end of the file after the previous write. You would need to seek back to the beginning of the file to output what you just wrote, but `bash` doesn't provide a way to seek. The best you can do is reopen the file for reading, either by closing and reopening file descriptor 3 or by opening on another file descriptor.

Since the goal is to read the file after its only link has been removed, you'll have to open *another* file descriptor for reading before you delete it.

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
exec 3> "$tmpfile"
exec 4< "$tmpfile"

rm "$tmpfile"

>&3 cat <<EOS
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOS

cat <&4
```

Although 3 and 4 both refer to the same file, they each maintain a separate file pointer. There's no need to open 3 for reading and writing; you can write to the file on descriptor 3, then read the contents from descriptor 4.

Comment: Thank you. To accomplish "reopen the file for reading, either by closing and reopening file descriptor 3 or by opening on another file descriptor" -- do I need to leave the actual file intact?  That is, do I have to give up the `rm "$tmpfile"` trick?  If not, can you add an example of how I'd actually close and reopen the FD?

Comment: Add `exec 4< "$tmpfile"` before you remove the file; then `cat <&4` after you write to it on file descriptor 3 will display the contents, since 4's file pointer will not have been advanced yet.